# Create admin user in magento 2 using commmand line

Tags: magento2, command-line, user

> create admin user using command line...
>
> ```
> php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='username' --admin-password='password' --admin-email='admin@admin.com' --admin-firstname='Admin' --admin-lastname='Admin'
> ```

Comment: what's wrong in your command? this is correct did you get any errors? describe your issue

Comment: Can u explain what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Your password needs both alphabet and alphanumeric characters

Comment: Yes..... you password should be both alphabet and alphanumeric characters ...

Comment: You're asking something?